# New Firemonkey iOS application - File not found unit1.lfm

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I started my first iOS application in Firemonkey, and the compiler immediately started complaining "File not found unit1.lfm". There is no such file in my project, and my application has no main form, just a unit with a form referenced...

```
{$R *.lfm}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This is a pretty funny corner case.  Maybe they should not let you create a new Firemonkey project without this option turned on.

Comment: Or maybe they should fix it where you can use Firemonkey with this option disabled - because now if I want to do a VCL app I have to switch it and restart my IDE again. Well, not have to, but I hate the embedded designer, having to switch from form to code, etc.

Comment: Is this in Quality Central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm asking/answering this Q/A style. I faced this issue and quickly knew what was wrong, and a lot of other people are bound to face this.

This is because the IDE's form designer for iOS (and all Firemonkey) applications requires that you have the "Embedded Designer" enabled. By default, this is enabled in these later versions of Delphi which have the option. However, many people disable this to mimic the old fashioned Delphi versions (where the forms are floating separate from everything else). These forms cannot be shown as their own windows in Delphi XE2, so they need to be designed in the embedded designer.

To fix this, go to "Tools > Options > VCL Designer" and then check the option "Embedded Designer". This will require you to restart your IDE for it to take effect.

[image]

Unfortunately, you will have to delete any saved files and create your project again. The links are broken after you've started a new project with this disabled. (technically it can be recovered, but it's easier to start over anyway)